# Ubuntu Software does not work in Ubuntu 16.04 on ChromeBook

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel, virtualbox, chromebook

On my Chromebook after installing Ubuntu using Crouton, whenever you try to install something using Ubuntu Software, it comes up with this.

Detailed errors from the package manager follow:

```
no plugin could handle
 gs_plugin_app_install
```

which is confusing. Whenever I use Synaptic, it still goes back to that once I try to open the package. The other question is that when I try using VirtualBox it runs, but once I try to start a VM it gives me this message:

```
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded 
or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. 
Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module 
by executing 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root.
```

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT. modprobe vboxdrv gives this: `modprobe:FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.241-19420-g5a63ca2874a0` and when I do `sudo virtualbox` it opens and in XTerm (that's what I'm using to run commands) it says Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate headers, most likely linux-headers-g5a63ca2874a0.

I think it just needs to be forced into open the headers which I've tried to install about 8 times, so if you have any tips that would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Two things 16.04 is EOL in April and why not just install Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 from a CD or USB?

Comment: Didn't think of that, I use it so that I can go back and forth between ChromeOS and Ubuntu quickly; this is the tutorial I used https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#1-overview